# What is the current state of XSLT 2.0 availability within .NET

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

The latest I can find from the web and blogosphere indicate that Microsoft's XML team would be [supporting XSLT 2.0 (now that it was a full blown W3C recommendation)](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/01/29/xslt-2-0.aspx).  I can't find anything beyond that.

What's the current status?  Is it available in .NET 3.5/4.0 or are they stuck with XSLT 1.1 and pushing XQUERY and LINQ?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net

Comment: Any update in 2018 ?

Comment: @userSteve - Nope.

Comment: You can give the bounty to Dirk directly. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath and XSLT 2.0 for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not supported by Microsoft and there hasn't been any anouncement I'm aware of. Where did you hear about that?

#### UPDATE (after you added the link to the XML Team Blog):

It seems that Microsoft changed their strategy according to [this interview](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/11/16/chris-lovett-interview.aspx) with Chris Lovett, a Program Manager on the XML team at Microsoft, later the same year, so it's all about LINQ:

> As for XSLT 2.0 - we’ve heard from
> customers and understand the
> improvements in XSLT 2.0 over XSLT
> 1.0, but right now we’re in the middle of a big strategic investment in LINQ
> and EDM for the future of the data
> programming platform which we think
> will create major improvements in
> programming against all types of data.
> But we are always re-evaluating our
> technology investments  so if your
> readers want to ramp up their volume
> on XSLT 2.0 please ask them to drop us
> a line with their comments.

If you want to use XSLT/XPath 2.0 with .NET you could use [**Saxon.NET**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxondotnet/). However, this is just the Java version of Saxon running inside IKVM. It has a significant size in the range of 30 MB and when I tried it the performance did not seem overwhelming (This was a very basic test though so the result might be different with a typical stylesheet).

Comment: This really sucks.  We really need to start lobbying MS to get an XSLT 2.0 processor started!

Comment: I don't think they will very be implementing XSLT 2.0, unless they have changed their mind since 2004. They like XQuery.
See:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dareobasanjo/archive/2004/05/13/131166.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2004/05/13/130969.aspx

Comment: @Jay Stevens: Saxon.NET is slower than XslCompiledTransform, but still has good speed.

Comment: Check feature request http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3795831-native-support-for-xpath-2-0-or-xslt-2-0-in-net

Answer (score 2):

[XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/) now includes a full XSLT 2.0 implementation for .NET.  It doesn't yet compile to MSIL, but that is in the pipeline.

Comment: XQSharp is a commercial product, for those that want to know.

Comment: So is Saxon(.NET), except that there is entry level Home Edition version that is free to use.