# XML transformation using XSLT version 2

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to transform XML using XSLT version 2.0 but getting below exception:

*Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.*

Later I came to know that Microsoft doesn't support XSLT version 2.0. 
Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831300/what-is-the-current-state-of-xslt-2-0-availability-within-net). It suggests to use some third party tool. But these tools have some license fee associated. Is there any similar freeware available?

[Edit]

I tried to use SaxonHe

```
  public static void Func( string xsltFile,string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {

        var  xslt = new FileInfo(xsltFile);
        var input = new FileInfo(inputFile);
        var output = new FileInfo(outputFile);
        // Compile stylesheet
        var processor = new Processor(false);
        var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));


        // Do transformation to a destination
        var destination = new DomDestination();
        using (var inputStream = input.OpenRead())
        {
            var transformer = executable.Load();
            transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(input.DirectoryName));
            transformer.Run(destination);
        }

        destination.XmlDocument.Save(output.FullName);
    }
```

It's not working giving null reference exception on last statement. Actually destination.XmlDocument is getting null value.

Comment: Saxon 9 HE is open source, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your suggestion. I tried to use use Saxon 9 He but its not working for me. I have edited question with details.

Comment: I can try to help using Saxon with C# but I think you should first state what is the aim, do you want to create a result document on disk? Your code tries to create an `XmlDocument` only to save it to a file it seems, so I wonder whether that is the only way you found to write the result to a file or whether you want to have the result in an `XmlDocument` and as a file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to simply create the transformation result as a file then you don't need a DomDestination, you can use a Serializer, as in

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestTransform("XSLTFile1.xslt", "XMLFile1.xml", "Result1.xml");
    }

    public static void TestTransform(string xsltFile, string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {

        var xslt = new FileInfo(xsltFile);
        var input = new FileInfo(inputFile);
        var output = new FileInfo(outputFile);

        // Compile stylesheet
        var processor = new Processor(false);
        var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));


        using (var inputStream = input.OpenRead())
        {
            var transformer = executable.Load();
            transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(input.DirectoryName));

            var serializer = new Serializer();

            using (var resultStream = output.OpenWrite())
            {
                serializer.SetOutputStream(resultStream);
                transformer.Run(serializer);
            }
        }


    }
}
```